# How do I import helper functions that rely on the psycopg2 cursor object?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have created some helper functions for basic Postgres actions such as create connection, create cursor, create table, create columns and so on. I saved the functions in a seperate .py file and added to path. I am able to import the file and see them when I call `dir()` but when I try to call the function which depends on the `psycopg2.cursor()` object it returns a Name error.

I tried making it into a class to access objects that way with no success.
I also tried calling the cur function within the my_psycop.py file as well.

```
#This is from the helper function file

import psycopg2

def connect_and_make_cursor(host, dbname, user, pw):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(f"host={host}, dbname={dbname} user = {user} password = {pw}")
        conn.set_session(autocommit = True)
        cur = conn.cursor()
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(e)
    return cur


#this is from the file in which I am attempted to import the functions

import my_psycop
from password import password
#psycopg2 = my_psycop.psycopg2

dir(my_psycop)
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 'close_connection',
 'connect_and_make_cursor',
 'create_database',
 'create_table',
 'insert_columns',
 'insert_rows',
  'psycopg2']

 cur = my_psycop.connect_and_make_cursor("127.0.0.1", 'postgres', 'postgres', password )

my_psycop.create_database('new_db')
```

The following is the error traceback:

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-5eb39fff83a2> in <module>()
----> 1 my_psycop.create_database('new_db')

c:\python36\lib\site-packages\my_psycop.py in create_database(db_name)
     12 def create_database(db_name):
     13     try:
---> 14         cur.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name}")
     15     except psycopg2.Error as e:
     16         print(e)

NameError: name 'cur' is not defined
```

I have never used custom functions in such a way that rely on a separate library and understand this is some kind of scoping issue but I just can't figure it out. It would be wonderful to not have to have these  functions in every single file I create going forward. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried adding commas between arguments in `conn = psycopg2.connect(f"host={host}, dbname={dbname}, user={user}, password={pw}")`?

Comment: thats just the weird SQL syntax associated with psycopg2

Comment: oh, after checking the pscopg2, you should remove your comma after the host. sample from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_psycopg2_with_PostgreSQL is like `conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'"`

Comment: nice catch, strangely it has been still working with that comma. Though not when I import to another file. The functions work fine when inside the file im running them. Only issue is when I try to import them.

Comment: I just happened to browse the code while editing your question, I may not be able to help further, sorry.

Comment: thought that counts. Cheers